# jquery: simultaneously slide and rotate an image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have an application where I need to slide and rotate an image at the same time.  Specifically, if you imagine a CD case, I need to slide the CD out of the case (say to the right), and rotate it 360 degrees as it comes out.  The rotation needs to be from the center of the CD image (as expected)

Can someone assist?  I've been at it a few hours with very limited success.

Thanks Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reliably rotate an image by an arbitrary degree with JavaScript. Look into [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) which uses "SVG W3C Recommendation and VML as a base for creating graphics." It is completely browser-independent and allows [image rotation by arbitrary degrees](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html).

See [image](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#image) and [rotate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#rotate) for more info.

Comment: Thanks guys -- what about the slide, can I do that at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK jQuery doesn't directly support rotation as part of its animation (probably wrong though!). Have a look at Raphael.js for great animation support (its dead easy to use if you know jQuery).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer -- adding in the slide would be the translate function I guess ...

Answer (score 1):

You can see a demo for image rotation [**here**](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer.  Adding in the slide I guess would be the translate function ...